# Change the Layout in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

PROBLEM :::
I want to change the layout, more specifically hide or show the components in the layout based on the user click events.

I have attached a screen recording of the final result.
[PLEASE VISIT THIS LINK FOR FINAL RESULT](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1k6_aIuyEqzi5PaclAhp7t_VUIg_JzM7Y?usp=sharing)

THINGS WHICH I CAN TRY :::
Create same layout with components and load that layout when user clicks on button. But I know it's the very inefficient way.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow . Kindly provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a isVisible value and add the layout between an if braces.

```
val isVisible = remember { mutableState(false) }
if (isVisible) {
  content()
}
Button(onClick = { isVisible.value = true })
```